# Execute a query to MySQL from Oozie

Tags: mysql, oozie

Does oozie have anything which will allow me to execute a query on MySQL (or any other relational database for that matter?)

I need a step in my oozie job to query a mysql table and extract a date. the job should proceed only if the date is equal or greater than current time stamp.

All my google searches showed that Oozie can do a HIVE query but I need to query a MySQL Table.

What is the best way? should I write a custom EL function?

Comment: Jdbc client will do the work.

Comment: Can you point me to an example? thank you so much for your help

Comment: If you are using Java then use any Java client to query from database and pass output to switch case of oozie to decide next step.

Comment: I saw this tutorial. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Java+Cookbook
it just executes the java program. but how about extracting a value and then comparing it to something?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture output from shell script and pass it to java action.In the shell script , echo the property like 'dateVariable=${DATE}' and add the capture-output element int the shell action. This will let you capture dateVariable from shell script.In the java action, You can pass the captured variable as parameter as ${wf:actionData('shellAction')['dateVariable']} where shellAction is the shell action name.

Sample workflow :-

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4"
name="Test workflow">
<start to="shellAction" />
<action name="shellAction">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <exec>test_script.sh</exec> <file>${nameNode}/${workFlowLocation}/Scripts/test_script.sh#test_script.sh</file>          
        <capture-output />
    </shell>
    <ok to="JavaAction" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>

<action name="JavaAction">
    <java>
        <main-class>com.test.TestDriver</main-class>
        <arg>${wf:actionData('shellAction')['dateVariable']}</arg>
        <capture-output />
    </java>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>

<kill name="fail">
    <message>Job failed, error
        message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end" />
```

In the shell script ,echo the value as below

echo "dateVariable=${dateValue}"

reference: [stack similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873891/passing-parameters-from-one-action-to-another-in-oozie)